# Only execute INSERT when if statement is true

Tags: mysql

I'd like to execute a line of INSERT, but only when an if condititonal is true.

Here's a basic example (just to simplify the question) in psuedo code.

```
"If there is a user id = 5 in the users table (using SELECT), execute: INSERT INTO someOtherTable ... ()"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if users.id is primary key or at least unique

```
INSERT INTO someOtherTable
SELECT 123, 456, 'a string value'
FROM users
WHERE id = 5
```

for non unique test you can use the special table DAUL

```
INSERT INTO someOtherTable
SELECT 123, 456, 'a string value'
FROM DUAL
WHERE 5 IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 5)
```

Comment: Are 123, 456, 'a string value' the values you would normally specify in the VALUES() clause?
Just to be clear here; I don't want to insert values coming from the SELECT statement. I'd like to first execute one type of query (checking if some query involving other tables is true), then do the INSERT with values coming from PHP variables.

Comment: yes, there are exemple value `INSERT INTO t VALUES(123,456,'a')` AND `INSERT INTO t SELECT 123,456,'a'` is Equal